# Having issues with MVN Version command showing versions already updated

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

I am updating my maven dependencies. I ran "`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`" in terminal and i receive the dependencies that have newer versions. Example:

```
[INFO] io.projectreactor:reactor-test........3.4.28->3.5.4
[INFO] io.projectreactor:reactor-tools.......3.4.28->3.5.4
[INFO] io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-adapter..3.4.10->3.5.1
```

I look up the dependency on mvn repository to verify that its an updated version. Using visual code in my pom.xml file I inlcude that dependency in pom.xml file. I save and run the command "`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`" again and output is the same.

```
[INFO] io.projectreactor:reactor-test........3.4.28->3.5.4
[INFO] io.projectreactor:reactor-tools.......3.4.28->3.5.4
[INFO] io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-adapter..3.4.10->3.5.1
```

I reloaded the project, switched IDEs and same issue. This is how my pom.xml file looks like:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupid>io.projectreactor</groupid>
           <artifactid>reactor-tools</artifactid>
           <version>3.5.4</version>
       </dependency>
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupid>io.projectreactor.addons</groupid>
           <artifactid>reactor-adapter</artifactid>
           <version>3.5.1</version>
       </dependency>
....
```

I checked my external libraries and the dependencies do appear there with correct version. Is this just an issue with mvn command?

Comment: This is probably an issue with your POM. Could you please post the complete POM?